# git '~outside repository at~' error occur

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

i'm using Mac OS now.

1. if i make folder name by **Korean**
2. command change directory in terminal
3. command `git add ~file` error occur (git:fatal: directory1 is outside repository at directory1)
   i command `git add .` it is working..

if i make folder by English it is working nice.

i already tried change directory and lots of command so i think it is errored only i add one file.

i found all of StackOverflow and Github VSCODE but they can't help me

Comment: Don't know how `~` is playing there there but you do know that in UNIX systems (or linux), `~` has a special meaning, right?

Comment: ~ means file directory path!!

Comment: well.... In UNIX and linux (or rather, GNU.. anyway), it means `users's home directory`. How about you try without `~`?

Comment: I opened my git English named folder with VSCODE workspace, all of commands work very well.. but if I opened my Korean named git folder with VSCODE, it doesn't work when I add only one file to my git.